# Different MD5 hash with mbedtls and openssl

Tags: cryptography, md5, mbedtls

I'm trying to get MD5 hash with mbedtls by this code:

```
#include "mbedtls/base64.h"
#include "mbedtls/md5.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void app_main() {
  unsigned char hash_source[] = "This is a test..";
  size_t hash_source_len = sizeof(hash_source);
  unsigned char hash_destination[16];
  size_t hash_destination_len = 16;
  unsigned char base64_md5[25];

  mbedtls_md5_context md5_ctx;

  mbedtls_md5_init(&md5_ctx);
  mbedtls_md5_starts_ret(&md5_ctx);
  mbedtls_md5_update_ret(&md5_ctx, hash_source, hash_source_len);
  mbedtls_md5_finish_ret(&md5_ctx, hash_destination);
  mbedtls_md5_free(&md5_ctx);

  size_t base_md5len = 0;
  mbedtls_base64_encode(base64_md5, 25, &base_md5len, hash_destination,
                        hash_destination_len);
  printf("base md5: %s (%d)\n", base64_md5,
         base_md5len); // <- base md5: 62mujHCdeZzR5CkMIruNNQ== (24)
}
```

It returns `62mujHCdeZzR5CkMIruNNQ==` as md5 base64 for input as `This is a test..`, but all other world returns `A3veNGT6JuskB2Flv+cPpg==` md5 hash for the same input, e.g. Node.JS:

```
import crypto from "crypto";

console.log(
  "md5 base64:",
  crypto.createHash("md5").update("This is a test..").digest("base64")
); // <- md5 base64: A3veNGT6JuskB2Flv+cPpg==
```

or OpenSSL:

```
echo -n "This is a test.." | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | openssl enc -base64
A3veNGT6JuskB2Flv+cPpg==
```

Why could it be? And how can I receive "normal" md5 hash at mbedtls? Thx!

Comment: What is the value of `sizeof(hash_source)`? You want the length of the string here, excluding the terminating `\0` byte. Or use `sizeof(hash_source) - 1`

Comment: Thx a lot! It was the source of issue!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the library, but your incorrect usage of `sizeof`.
In `C`, `sizeof` used with char arrays needs special recommendation.

If you replace the line

```c
size_t hash_source_len = sizeof(hash_source);
```

with

```c
size_t hash_source_len = 16;
```

it will provide the same result (`A3veNGT6JuskB2Flv+cPpg==`)

`sizeof(char[])` will always be equal to `sizeof(char *)`, which, for deterministic lengths, will return the "C string" length, that is, including the terminating null byte (in this case, 17).